# Should I address more far-reaching issues not relevant to the answer of the question?

Tags: discussion, answers

It happens now and then, that I see deeper, more fundamental issues in the code posted for a seemingly trivial question. Some examples would be:

- A user asking about retrieving some records with `ActiveRecord`, but the code posted is vulnerable to SQL injection.
- A user asking about how to set up his associations in his `Rails` models, but the code reveals some serious flaws in the application design.

In these cases, the immediate question can easily be answered in a single paragraph, but the more far-reaching problems revealed by the code beg an answer that inspires a deeper understanding of some broader topic.

As far as I can see, I have three options:

1. Ignore it and strictly address the question asked.
2. Address the question, but inform the user there is more to it than it seems, and point them to some resources where they can learn more.
3. Extend the answer to address both the question and the more far-reaching issues, making it more discursive and substantially longer.

Whenever I see these kind of questions, I tend to attribute it to unwillful ignorance on the part of the poster. This makes me conflicted. Learning about the possible issues would certainly be helpful to the poster, but the exhaustive digression required becomes prohibitive.

What does SO think about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are additional issues with the question itself, like the user taking a bass-ackwards approach to his problem, that might indicate an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Or he has simply simplified his problem so much, what's left does not convey a sensible broader picture of what he's trying to do. Thus insisting on trying to piece together the broader picture will leave you scratching your head.

If the additional problems are only about the presentation, consider correcting them *in the question* (take care to use a *suitable edit-summary*) to avoid derailing the answers. That's part of clarifying the question. Unless it's blindingly obvious it's only a presentation issue, commenting to the OP and letting him edit is better most of the time though.

In any case, I advise you to mention any severe failings, especially those with security implications, in an addendum to the answer though, in order to  make sure the OP and any other reader are made aware of them and  avoid any negative reactions provoked by ignoring them.

Separate them clearly from the actual answer, you might have to remove them later if the asker clarifies his question. And anyway, they aren't the focus of the question.